# Перегрузка метода внутри класса в Python

Tags: python

Всю жизнь писал на Java, начал изучать python в связи с чем появилось много вопросов. Например в Java можно писать вот так:

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private void testrunner()
    {

    }

    private void testrunner(int i)
    {

    }

    private void testrunner(String c)
    {

    }
}
```

Как написать так же на питоне ?
Ну вот пишу я так IDE сразу ругаться начинает

```
class test:
def testrunner(self):
    pass
def testrunner(self,a):
    pass
```

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Как указать в Python чтобы аргументом функции был именно список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/951110/1365), [метод `__add__` без if'а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1190940/1365)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В Python нет возможности перегрузить метод класса, как например в Java или С.

Но есть костыль. Метод может иметь значения параметров по-умолчанию, что совместно с проверкой типа аргумента позволит вам сделать то, что вы хотите:

```
from types import *

class Test(object):

    def testrunner(self, i=None):
        if isinstance(i, str):     
            print 'c: ', i
        elif isinstance(i, int):
            print 'b: ', i
        else:
            print 'a'
```

Comment: Следует упомянуть что не стоит писать Java код, используя Python синтаксис. Например, не обязательно всё внутрь классов пихать — в Питоне можно использовать свободные функции. К наличию многочисленных `isinstance()` в коде следует с подозрением относится — это может указывать на проблемы в интерфейсе. Следует рассмотреть альтернативные варианты, например, которые опираются на duck typing без isinstance костылей.

Answer (score 0):

В стандартной библиотеке Python есть очень полезный декоратор, который позволяет одной и той же функции обрабатывать различные типы данных по-разному [image: работа с декоратором]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте в ответы исходный код с помощью разметки markdown, а не в виде скриншота

Comment: Ставлю минус, т.к. оформление ответа все еще не исправлено.