# Как указать в Python чтобы аргументом функции был именно список

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, типизация, динамическая-типизация

Когда я передаю аргумент в функцию, как я понимаю, функция не понимает с каким именно типом данных я хочу работать. Суть вопроса в том, могу ли я указать явно, чтобы в функцию в качестве аргумента передавался именно список/словарь/кортеж... и в теле функции я работал именно со списком/словарем/кортежем...?

Вот что у меня получается:

```
def print_magicians (magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)


def great_magicians (magicians):
    for i in range(len(magicians)):
        temp = magicians[i]
        magicians[i] = "Great " + temp


magicians_list = ["Гудини", "Коперфильд", "Блейн"]
print_magicians(magicians_list)

great_magicians(magicians_list)
print_magicians(magicians_list)
```

Функции def great_magicians (magicians) я в качестве аргумента принимает или ожидает любой тип данных (не знаю как правильно выразиться) и в итоге не могу с ним работать как со списком (вызывать его методы). А если, допустим, туда передадут не в качестве аргумента не список, а строку или число, то что получиться ? После Си подобных языков в которых была строгая типизация не очень все понятно.

Comment: Например так: `def print_magicians(magicians: list):`, но это только подсказка о типе, интепретатор не будет ругаться если туда попадет объект другого типа

Comment: А как мне сделать чтобы я мог работать с аргументом как со списком (вызывать его методы) ?

Comment: Просто вызывайте методы, например `magicians.append(1)`

Comment: После добавления magicians: list как аргумента, появилась возможность вызывать методы списка. А если можно по подробнее как этот механизм работает ?

Comment: В отличие от type(), функция isinstance() специально создана для проверки принадлежности данных определенному классу (типу данных): `b = [1,2,3]` -> `isinstance(b, list)` -> `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помимо явного указания типа аргумента в аргументах функции, можно внутри функции проверить тип аргумента. Например:

```
def great_magicians (magicians : list):
    if type(magicians) is list:
        #Какой-то код, если magicians - список
    else:
        #Какой-то код, если magicians - не список (например, можно поднять исключение)
```

Также можно явно указать тип возвращаемого значения. Например:

```
def great_magicians (magicians : list) -> bool:
    #Какой-то код
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен [@functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

```
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def main(args):
    raise TypeError("Unacceptable data type")


@main.register(dict)
def _(args):
    print("That\'s dict!", args)


@main.register(list)
def _(args):
    print("That\'s list!", args)


main({1: 2})
main([1, 2])
main(10)
```

Вывод:

```
That's dict! {1: 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
That's list! [1, 2]
  File "C:/Users/ypank/py_proj/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    main(10)
  File "C:\Users\ypank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\functools.py", line 803, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "C:/Users/ypank/py_proj/main.py", line 6, in main
    raise TypeError("Unacceptable data type")
TypeError: Unacceptable data type
```