# метод __add__ без if'а

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

решил сделать класс `Vec2`:

```
class Vec2():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    
    def __add__(self, num):
        if type(num) == Vec2:
            return Vec2(self.x + num.x, self.y + num.y)
        return Vec2(self.x + num, self.y + num)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}  {self.y}"
```

И появился вопрос, могу ли я реализовать метод `__add__` без `if`'а?

примерно как в этом коде на c++:

```cpp
vec2 operator+(vec2& v) {
    return vec2(x + v.x, y + v.y);
}
vec2 operator+(double s) {
    return vec2(x + s, y + s);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188666/python-operator-overloading-a-specific-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью декоратора `typedispatch` из библиотеки [fastcore](https://pypi.org/project/fastcore/):

```
from fastcore.dispatch import typedispatch


class _Vec2:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}  {self.y}"


class Vec2(_Vec2):
    @typedispatch
    def __add__(self, num: _Vec2):
        return Vec2(self.x + num.x, self.y + num.y)
    
    @typedispatch
    def __add__(self, num):
        return Vec2(self.x + num, self.y + num)


print(Vec2(1, 1) + 2)
print(Vec2(1, 1) + Vec2(1, 2))
```

Вывод:

```
3  3
2  3
```

Пришлось выделить отдельный класс `_Vec2` из-за того, что если указывать свой же класс в аннотации, то начинает ругаться на необъявленный символ `Vec2` (если использовать строковую аннотацию `"Vec2"` или добавить `from __future__ import annotations`, то ошибку выкинет внутри `fastcore.dispatch`).

Обзор библиотеки fastcore:
[fastcore: An Underrated Python Library](https://fastpages.fast.ai/fastcore/)

---

Реализация с помощью [`singledispatchmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) из стандартной библиотеки Python (на мой вкус менее красивый вариант из-за того, что нужно менять имя метода на подчеркивание, зато без дополнительных модулей):

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod


class _Vec2:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}  {self.y}"


class Vec2(_Vec2):
    @singledispatchmethod
    def __add__(self, num):
        return Vec2(self.x + num, self.y + num)
    
    @__add__.register
    def _(self, num: _Vec2):
        return Vec2(self.x + num.x, self.y + num.y)


print(Vec2(1, 1) + 2)
print(Vec2(1, 1) + Vec2(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```py
class Vec2():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    
    def __add__(self, num):
        return Vec2(self.x + getattr(num, 'x', num), self.y + getattr(num, 'y', num))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}  {self.y}"
```

Но это будет работать для любого класса, у которого есть член `x` или `y`.

А вообще, зачем это надо?

Comment: `А вообще, зачем это надо?` - "Ну во-первых это красиво" (с). Разные методы для аргументов разного типа делает код более декларативным. Тут скорее вопрос стиля, а не практики.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже вариант, но с `if`-ом:

```
    def __add__(self, num):
        dx = num.x if type(num) == Vec2 else num
        dy = num.y if type(num) == Vec2 else num
        return Vec2(self.x + dx, self.y + dy)
```